# MVC DevExpress Radio button list for Model

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, devexpress

I have a model class as shown below

```
 public class AddKeyModel
{
    public int Count { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// 0 - Trial
    /// 1 - License
    /// </summary>
    public bool LicenseType { get; set; }



    /// <summary>
    /// 0 - Lite
    /// 1 - Pro
    /// </summary>
    public int ProductType { get; set; }

}
```

I am using DevExpress MVC extensions but facing problem in displaying this data on view. can anybody tell me the exact code to show radio buttons and also set back the data to model while submitting data to controller.

this code is not working

```
@Html.DevExpress().RadioButton(
    settings =>
    {
        settings.Name = "Trial";
        settings.GroupName = "LicenseType";
    }).Bind(Model.LicenseType).GetHtml()

    @Html.DevExpress().Label(
        settings =>
        {
            settings.ControlStyle.CssClass = "label";
            settings.Text = "License";
            settings.AssociatedControlName = "License";
        }).GetHtml()


    @Html.DevExpress().RadioButton(
    settings =>
    {
        settings.Name = "License";
        settings.GroupName = "LicenseType";
    }).Bind(Model.LicenseType).GetHtml()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use RadioButtonList instead.

See the [How to use the CheckBoxList and RadioButtonList editors to edit Model fields](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Example/Details/E4125) example.